# How to use the LIKE clause in an XML column in Oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle

I have one column which contains XML data. The requirement is I need to have that column that has  tag in XML (This tag is always present somewhere in the middle of the XML). And for that, I am using

```
WHERE XML_DATA LIKE '%DateofBirth%
```

Is there any other better way of doing this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean the `<DateofBirth>` tag can appear in different paths? Eg `/a/b/DateofBirth`, `a/c/d/DateofBirth`? Do you have namespaces defined for these different paths? Also, what version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is defined as XMLType (and if not it probably should be) you can use `existsnode()`:

```
WHERE EXISTSNODE(xml_data, '/DateofBirth') = 1;
```

Also, you should consider building an XML Index on it. It depends whether you're going to be doing enough of such searches to justify the cost of maintaining an index. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_indexing.htm#ADXDB4319)

If the column is not defined as XMLType LIKE is the best you can do, unless you want to define an Oracle Text index.

---

APC sez: upon reflection this answer may not be useful to the Seeker. I have asked them for additional details. Depending on their response I may amend or delete this answer.